# jQuery Tab Design refreshing only one tab content

Tags: jquery, tabs

i'm using jQuery-UI for my tab design and while i have a form in my second tab ,when i'm filling it with data and pressing "Submit" , the entire page is loaded (i know that since the form is in the second tab and the page returns to show the first tab after Submit).

how can i make only the current tab loading/refresh ?

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="tabsJquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Trader's Friend</h1>
<h2></h2>


<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Market Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/page1.html">Portfolios</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

**page1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create New Portfolio</title>
    <script src="portfolio.js"></script>
    <script src="tabsJquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form  name="portfolio" id="portfolio" method="post" onsubmit="createNewPortfolio()">
    <p class="ui-widget-header" id="newPortfolioHeader" >General Info</p>
    Portfolio   Name:   <input type="text" id="portfolioName" name="portfolioName" value="test1"><br>
    Owner First Name:   <input type="text" id="ownerFName" name="ownerFName" value="eyal"><br>
    Owner Last  Name:   <input type="text" id="ownerLName" name="ownerLName" value="becker"><br>
    Init Amount:        <input type="number" id="initAmount" name="initAmount" value="1000"><br>
    Date:               <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" ><br>
    <p class="ui-widget-header" id="newPortfolioHeader" >Risk Management</p>
    Stocks (%):           <input type="number" id="stocksPerc" name="stocksPerc" value="50"><br>
    NonStocks (%):         <input type="number" id="nonStocksPerc" name="nonStocksPerc" value="50"><br>
    Risk In Stocks (%):    <input type="number" id="riskInStocksPerc" name="riskInStocksPerc"value="5"><br>
    Risk In nonStocks (%): <input type="number" id="riskInNonStocksPerc" name="riskInNonStocksPerc" value="5"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**createNewPortfolio() :**

```
function createNewPortfolio() {


    var portfolioName = document.portfolio.portfolioName.value;

    var ownerFname = document.portfolio.ownerFName.value;
    var ownerLname = document.portfolio.ownerLName.value;
    var initAmount = document.portfolio.initAmount.value;
    var dateVal = document.portfolio.date.value;
    //alert(portfolioName + ownerFname + ownerLname + dateVal);
    var stocksPerc = document.portfolio.stocksPerc.value;
    var nonStocksPerc = document.portfolio.nonStocksPerc.value;
    var riskInStocksPerc = document.portfolio.riskInStocksPerc.value;
    var riskInNonStocksPerc = document.portfolio.riskInNonStocksPerc.value;
    //alert(stocksPerc + nonStocksPerc + riskInStocksPerc + riskInNonStocksPerc);

    var myNewPortfolioJsonObj = {

        "general": {
            "portfolioName": portfolioName,
            "ownerFname": ownerFname,
            "ownerLname": ownerLname,
            "initAmount": initAmount,
            "date": dateVal
        },
        "riskManagement": {
            "stocksPerc": stocksPerc,
            "nonStocksPerc": nonStocksPerc,
            "riskInStocksPerc": riskInStocksPerc,
            "riskInNonStocksPerc": riskInNonStocksPerc
        }


    };
    //alert(JSON.stringify(myNewPortfolioJsonObj));
    localStorage.setItem('Portfolios', JSON.stringify(myNewPortfolioJsonObj));
     //event.preventDefault();
}
```

**tabsJquery.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    });
});
```

Thanks
Sivan

Comment: "how can i make only the current tab loading/refresh ?" AJAX.

Comment: thanks but can you be more specific ? i'm a fresh starter.